# Favicon not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, favicon

I've done everything I could find to make favicon work, but only on IE it doesn't work.

This is in the `<head>`

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//www.site.com/img/favicon.ico">
```

I tried to create a favicon with favicon.co.uk and favicon-generator.org/, but nothing works in IE.

It's 16x16 and a .ico file.

In google Chrome and Firefox it's working just fine.

When bookmarking in IE, it's also showing the icon. But not in the top bar.

What's wrong here ?

Edit:

I also tried this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: You can look the correct code here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122067/favicon-not-working-in-ie

Comment: @RémiBenoit there is no answer to that question

Comment: Sorry I meant looking at the code, actually the question is unrelated ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For who is interested:

It works now, I tried a different website to create the favicon and it worked.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.url.com/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: type="image/x-icon" was the answer for me

Answer (score 2):

Faced with same problem. Solved my case easily.

It seems IE doesn't accept favicons from subfolders. Try placing favicon.ico in root directory.

1. Place favicon file in root (/favicon.ico).
2. Rewrite head tags:

   `<link  rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">`

   `<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">`

Hope this helped

Answer (score 1):

Fix the typo of the image. Also try adding `type="image/x-icon"` to the image tag.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.site.com/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

---- Edit ----

It seems `rel="shortcut icon"` is proprietary to IE. The most used standard is to put the favicon at the root of your website and call it `favicon.ico`

If you can bear to have the same favicon for all your pages, this will be recognize by all browsers wihtout the need to declare it in the HTML.

More detail there : http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon

Comment: Is your image really an ico file (e.g. not renamed). Tried emptying the cache?

Comment: You have a typo in the file URL I think.

Comment: It is created with those sites as an .ico, I tried to empty the cache and the file URL is working as when bookmarking the page the favicon shows up

Comment: Try with an absolute URL and not a local one. And which IE version did you test?

Comment: And last try is to put it at root as `yoursite.com/favicon.ico`, apparently favicon tag is not a cross browser standard : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931533/why-isnt-my-favicon-appearing-in-ie7-8